# Reshape flat vectors with Keras and R for CNN

Tags: r, conv-neural-network, keras, shapes

I'm trying to make a CNN to classify EEG. 
My dataset is composed of 4320 observations. Each observation is a flat vector of 1440 column. It is composed of 8 electrode signal of 180ms $\left(  8*180=1440 \right)$.

I would like to use a 1D convolutional neural network [this article](https://blog.goodaudience.com/introduction-to-1d-convolutional-neural-networks-in-keras-for-time-sequences-3a7ff801a2cf), it explain how to make a 1D CNN on python using Keras. But I would like to do it using R.

I'm facing a problem when I want to reshape my signal. I guess I need to reshape the dataset from 4320*1440 to 4320*180*8, but I don't know how to achieve it.
I tried the function `x <- k_reshape(train.x, c(180,8))` but I got the following error :

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <type 'dict'> to Tensor. Contents: {'C4_086': 31.419, etc...
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I was using the wrong function. 
To reshape a flat vector the right way is to use a `layer_reshape` as first layout.

Here is my network as an example :

```
num_time_periods = 180
num_sensors = 8
input_shape = num_sensors*num_time_periods

model = keras_model_sequential()
model %>%
  layer_reshape(c(num_time_periods, num_sensors), input_shape = input_shape) %>%
  layer_conv_1d(100, 10, activation = 'relu', input_shape = input_shape) %>%
  layer_conv_1d(100, 10, activation = 'relu', input_shape = input_shape) %>%
  layer_max_pooling_1d(8) %>%
  layer_conv_1d(160, 10, activation = 'relu') %>%
  layer_conv_1d(160, 10, activation = 'relu') %>%
  layer_global_average_pooling_1d() %>%
  layer_dropout(0.5) %>%
  layer_dense(2, activation = 'softmax')
```